# Creating a trigger to insert records from a table to another one

Tags: sql

When I want to get values from one table to another table its work but when I want edit values, it adds the new values to tbl_ItemDetails. I just need to update existing rows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateItemDetails ON tbl_PurchaseDetails

FOR INSERT AS

DECLARE @PurchaseID VARCHAR(20)

DECLARE @Quantity INT

DECLARE @WarehouseID VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @PurchaseID=(PurchaseID) FROM INSERTED

SELECT @Quantity=(ItemQuantity) FROM INSERTED

SELECT @WarehouseID=(WarehouseID) FROM INSERTED

INSERT INTO 

tbl_ItemDetails

(PurchaseID,Quantity,WarehouseID)

VALUES

(@PurchaseID,@Quantity,@WarehouseID)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged c?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server maybe? (If so, please add that tag. If not, please add a tag for your database system. Triggers are vendor specific). If it is SQL Server, it's broken. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or **multiple** rows.

Comment: Please post either a SQL Fiddle of your table schema or post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with this:
you should never write triggers that can't handle sets.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateItemDetails ON tbl_PurchaseDetails
FOR INSERT AS

UPDATE itm
SET  PurchaseID=i.PurchaseID
    ,Quantity=i.ItemQuantity
    ,WarehouseID=i.WarehouseID
FROM INSERTED i
INNER JOIN tbl_ItemDetails itm ON i.???=itm.???
--I have no idea what your join clause should be as I don't know your data structure
```

Comment: I need help to get values from tables. I have one database "MechanicalDatabase" and I have 4 tables. I want to get the values "Material" and "Price" from table "a", "b", "c" to table "Report". I mean that when I write something to table a, b, c I want to see these values on table "report"

Table "a" Reference, Material,Price

Table "b" Reference, Material,Price

Table "c" Reference, Material,Price

Table "report" Material,Price